# Change Password not taking effect with Novell LDAP Modification for Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap

For anyone who can help - I have code working fine in `Asp/Net Core 2.0` that can add entries to LDAP using the `Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard (2.3.8)` library. I also update properties and everything is error free. However when I update a password it doesn't take. I can't login in using the same password I just set through code. I'm wondering if anyone has run into this, do I need to encode it a special way and/or do any additional steps?

Here's what my code looks like - pretty simple and it works without causing an error:

```
modList.Add(new LdapModification(LdapModification.REPLACE, new LdapAttribute("pwdLastSet", "-1")));

modList.Add(new LdapModification(LdapModification.REPLACE, new LdapAttribute("userPassword", newPassword)));

LdapModification[] mods = new LdapModification[modList.Count];

mods = (LdapModification[])modList.ToArray(typeof(LdapModification));

string dn = String.Format("CN={0},CN={1},DC=WPD,DC=Local", displayName, "Users");

_conn.Modify(dn, mods);
```

Thanks!
Craig

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No I haven’t heard from anyone or figured it out myself. If you find an answer please let me know - thanks, Craig

Comment: I'm assuming you are using AD via LDAP - AD is a little bit special when interacting with it via LDAP protocol See here https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/issues/31 and here https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/issues/51 for solutions.

Comment: Ok thanks I’ll check this out - appreciate the help!

Comment: No solution yet :(

Comment: Nope @Gokulnath! *sigh*.. I'm going a different route now actually..

Comment: @CraigsterJ check out my answer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using "userPassword" attribute, I used "unicodePwd" attribute and changed the encoding, and it worked. The most **IMPORTANT** thing is to enclose the password in double quotes.

```
string password = "\"myNewStrongPassword\"";
var encodedBytes = SupportClass.ToSByteArray(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password));
var attributePassword = new LdapAttribute("unicodePwd", encodedBytes);
ldapConnection.Modify(YOUR_DISTINGUISHED_NAME, new LdapModification(LdapModification.REPLACE, attributePassword));
```

Comment: What is SupportClass? It's not part of Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard.

Comment: It seems i'ts no longer included. This is the original code:

    /// <summary>
    ///     Receives a byte array and returns it transformed in an sbyte array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="byteArray">Byte array to process</param>
    /// <returns>The transformed array</returns>
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public static sbyte[] ToSByteArray(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        var sbyteArray = new sbyte[byteArray.Length];
        for (var index = 0; index < byteArray.Length; index++)
            sbyteArray[index] = (sbyte) byteArray[index];
        return sbyteArray;
    }